# how to find namespace usages inside current C# document?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, namespaces

suppose I have a statement

> using Project.Auth.ClientModels;

So I have some classes that are part of this namespace and are being used in the current C# document. Is there a way in Visual Studio to get the list of those classes that are referencing the above namespace?

Comment: Are you looking to do this programmatically, or a simple `Edit>Find & Replace>Find in Files...` and searching for the namespace?

Comment: @NPras no, find and replace is not going to work. I don't want to find the namespace because there is just one line using ... so there is no need to find namespace.
I want to check what classes of this namespace have been used in the current document

Comment: `VS2022` > `View` > `Object Browser`

Comment: For a single document? Remove or comment the line and check the error messages.

Comment: Do you care about references that may be using a fully qualified type name at point of use and so wouldn't be found by using Oliver's suggestion?

Comment: not a best practice but it can be a workaround. Also, we can add namespace aliases to shorten the fully qualified type access. 

But would have been nice if we just had something like (shift + f12). The same shortcut that we have for variable references. I know Visual Studio is already able to do it when you have an auto-cleanup of unused namespaces in the settings. So when Visual Studio is already able to locate unused namespaces I am sure it is possible to locate the referenced usages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that fits your requirements to a certain extent. You can use Object Exlporer.

1. First, please click View=>Object Explorer

[image]

2. Find the namespace you are looking for in the Object Explorer. For example, mine is dbfirst, which contains the class EFContext I am looking for.

[image]

3. Then right-click EFContext and click Find All Rederence.

[image]

4. Finally, you only need to set the scope to "Current Document" to see whether this Document uses this class

[image]

Comment: read the question first. I am not asking for class references. Even so, there is no need to go this long way you can just just select the class name and press shift + f12 it will bring you all the references of that class.

Comment: This is indeed a shortcut. In this case, whether Oliver's solution is valid, you can delete "using Project.Auth.ClientModels;" so that you can see the information you want in the error message.